# codenameone sliding MenuBar bottom to top

Tags: codenameone

I have an issue to set bottom toolbar, I was able to set two sliders from the right and the left by setting a class that extends MenuBar. But now I have to put a sliding MenuBar but this one is from the bottom to top.
How can I do that??

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: Replacing menu bar is probably a bad idea, Toolbar should be able to do everything you need. I suggest providing a screenshot with the effect you are trying to achieve